# Acces to LinkedIn API for Apply Now button

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm trying to add an 'Apply by LinkedIn' button to my website. I realise the plugin was deprecatad and am trying to use the JS SDK to create this. What I currently have in place (as documented [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin)) will allow me to sign in to my account, however, the documentation doesn't go any further. How is the user to apply for a specific position, should this be referenced in the url somewhere? 
Also, I've submitted the application to access the API but have heard nothing back after 9 days.
Any feedback appreciated,
Thanks :)

Comment: No kidding. I've been waiting as well and I'm wondering what is supposed to happen when one clicks this button.